# Можно ли преобразовать переменную из одного типа в другой?

Tags: c#

Я имею класс Service

```
public  class Service
{
    public int Mass { get; set; }
    public int Mat { get; set; }
    public int SelCar { get; set; }

    public Service(int mat, int mass, int carCategories)
    {
        Mass = mass;
        Mat = mat;
        SelCar = carCategories;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Your order: Material-- { (Material.Materiale)Mat}, Massa--{Mass}, Car--{(Car.Carr)SelCar}";
    }
}
```

У класса Service два наследника:

```
class ServicePeople : Service
{
    private int quantity;
    // private int CarCategories = ;

    public  ServicePeople(int mat, int mass, int carCategories) : base( mat, mass,carCategories)
    {        
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString();
    }
}
```

```
class ServiceOfBigMass: Service
{
    public ServiceOfBigMass(int mat, int mass, int carCategories) : base(mat, mass, carCategories)
    {
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString();
    }
}
```

Главный класс:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //var ser = new ServicePeople(1,2,3);
    Console.WriteLine($"What are we going to transport?"+
        $"\n  1--{Material.Materiale.SAND},\n  2--{Material.Materiale.STONE},\n  3--{Material.Materiale.WOOD},\n" +
        $"  4--{Material.Materiale.PEOPLE},\n  5--{Material.Materiale.PRODUCTS},\n  6--{Material.Materiale.TOOLS}");
    
    int Mat = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    
    Console.WriteLine("Enter mass/quantity!");
    int Mass = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    
    var clien1 = new Client("Artemiy","Bogdanov");
    int vall = clien1.SelectMaterial(Mat);

    Console.WriteLine("Thanks for your choosing us!");            

    ServicePeople ser = new ServicePeople(Mat,Mass,vall);           

    Console.WriteLine(ser);           
}
```

Так же у меня есть класс Car в котором есть 3 вида машин под каждые авто под каждые задачи:

```
class Car
{
    public enum Carr : int
    {
        TRUCK = 1,
        PASSANGER_CAR = 2,
        BUS = 3
    }

    public Carr SelCar
    {
        get
        {
            return SelCar;
        }
        set
        {        
        }
    }
}
```

Выбор материала:

```
class Material
{
    public enum Materiale : int
    {
        SAND = 1,
        STONE = 2,
        WOOD = 3,
        PEOPLE = 4,
        PRODUCTS = 5,
        TOOLS = 6
    }
```

```
public Client(String Name, String SecondName)
{
    name = Name;
    secondName = SecondName;
}

public string GetClient
{
    get
    {
        return $"{name} {secondName}";
    }
}

public int SelectMaterial(int mat)// В зависимости от выбора 
//материала подставляется вид авто.
{
    switch (mat)
    {
        case 1://выбрал SEND значит приедет TRUCK
            v = 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            v = 1;
            break;
        case 3:
            v = 1;
            break;
        case 4://выбрал PEOPLE значит приедет BUS
            v = 3;
            break;
        case 5:
            v = 2;
            break;
        case 6:
            v = 2;
            break;
    }
    return v;
}
```

```
public static Service Select(int mat, int mass, int carCategories)
{
    if(mat ==1)
    {
        ServiceOfBigMass ser = new ServiceOfBigMass( mat, mass, carCategories);
        return  ser;
    }else if (mat == 2)
    {
        ServiceOfBigMass ser = new ServiceOfBigMass(mat, mass, carCategories);
        return ser;
    }
    else if (mat == 3)
    {
        ServiceOfBigMass ser = new ServiceOfBigMass(mat, mass, carCategories);
        return ser;
    }
    else if (mat == 4)
    {
        ServicePeople ser = new ServicePeople(mat, mass, carCategories);
        return ser;
    }
    else if (mat == 5)
    {
        ServiceOfSmallMass ser = new ServiceOfSmallMass(mat, mass, carCategories);
        return ser;
    }
    else if (mat == 6)
    {
        ServiceOfSmallMass ser = new ServiceOfSmallMass(mat, mass, carCategories);
        return ser;
    }
    Service ser2 = new Service(1,1,1);
    return ser2;
}
```

Как я могу изменить ServicePeople на ServiceOfBigMass?
Клиент выберит услуги по перевозке WOOD, я ему пришлю TRUCK, но услуга останеться быть ServicePeople. Может я вообще намудрил. Начал недавно.

Comment: Ну, хранить значение придётся в `object` или `dynamic`, а так ну обыкновенный switch/if. А как вы собираетесь _менять_ тип объекта? Расскажите вашу настоящую проблему.

Comment: А если я скажу не 1 число преобразовать, а 20? Мне под каждое switch создавать?

Comment: а чем число типа long отличается от числа типа int?

Comment: @АртемийБогданов: Мало ли как, например, можно функцию написать и вызвать её в цикле.

Comment: С консоли вы вводите всегда строку. Номер варианта, определяющего выбор переменной знаете. Передаёте в метод, который будет содержать switch...case и внутри будете делать парсинг в нужный тип и вызов нужного, строго типизированного метода. Имху, это решает исходную проблему причём без фокусов с object - всё строго типизировано будет.

Comment: @Grundy, может int от long мало чем, а вот MovingMass и MovinPeople меня беспокоят больше. Будет странно, если клиент попросит перевести людей, а я ему услугу по перевозке грузов предоставлю. А вот если я смогу поменять тип тогда встанет все на свои места. Я конечно могу подать ему автобус, но услуга уже не та, что надо.

Comment: @Артемий, а что мешает использовать наследование?

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий, нужен конкретный пример кода, который у вас не работает или не устраивает.

Comment: @aepot, я обновил вопрос. Посмотри пожалуйста.

Comment: @AK Говорит- исключение не обработано.

Comment: Вижу, что вопрос стал намного конкретнее -- это вам в плюс. Но... Вы пишете "исключение не обработано", это неконкретно. Назовите, какое исключение не обработано, их сотни различных. Также возможно понадобится описать при каких входных данных исключение появилось.

Comment: @AK, я в конец  вопроса добавил то что у меня получилось. Я создал стат.класс и там создавал каждый раз новый объект, меняя его тип и так это работает.

Answer (score 1):

```
int src = 1;
long dest = (long) src;
```